# How to update all table in postgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postgresql-10, node-postgres

I'm starting with postgreSQL and NodeJS and I have a table of office objects with the fields object_id(PK), inventory(varchar), area(FK) and description(text). This table must be updated weekly. How do I update the row according to the corresponding inventory value? That is, if the inventory(varchar) value of a row corresponds to the inventory(varchar) value of one of the new entries then update that row with the values of that entry. Is there a way to do it in one query?

The inventory(varchar) field is unique for each row.
For the queries I am using the modules "pg" and "pg-format".

Thank you so much.

I have tried to do it one by one but the table has 6000 rows. I don't know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Could you please share the ddl (in plain text) for the tables involved? And some examples. Please use https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Probably quickest way is to download the new weekly inventory into a temporary/staging  table and use that in a sub-select to update the existing table like : `update existing_table as e set (inventory, area, description) = (select inventory, area, description from temp_table as t where e.inventory = t.inventory);` See here [Update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) *Examples* for more examples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the UPDATE statement. Here's an example of how you can update all rows in a table

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET column1 = new_value1,
    column2 = new_value2,
    ...
WHERE condition;
```

The WHERE clause is optional. If you omit it, the update will be applied to all rows in the table. If you specify a condition, the update will be limited to the rows that match that condition.

for example:

```
UPDATE employees
SET salary = 5000;
```